# How do I execute the arguments to a bash function as root using the su command?

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell

I'm writing a script wherein I have a function that runs commands as root. This is so that it can use either sudo, doas, or su depending on what the user has installed. The function looks something like this:

```
as_root() {
    # $SU_CMD contains either sudo, doas --, or nothing
    if [[ -n $SU_CMD ]]; then
        $SU_CMD $@
    else
        su root -- $@
    fi
}
```

This does not work if neither sudo nor doas are available. Rather than executing the command as root, `su root -- <command>` writes `/usr/bin/<command>: /usr/bin/<command>: cannot execute binary file` to the terminal. I also tried `su -c "$@"` among other combinations, but no dice.

How would I go about executing the arguments to a bash function as root using su?

Comment: I think this is off-topic here, consider moving it to [su].

Comment: @oguzismail Why do you see this as off-topic? Also, if we are to move it anywhere, wouldn't [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) be more appropriate?

Comment: For it's more about user permissions. I don't see any problem with your script except missing quotes around `$@`. And yes, I guess it'd be on-topic on [unix.se] too

Comment: There's definitely a programming element, though, as expanding `SU_CMD` with the assumption that word-splitting will produce the correct sequence of arguments is an anti pattern.

Comment: @chepner Do you have any suggestions regarding how I could do that better?

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah, I tried adding qoutes. It still gives me `cannot execute binary file`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I thought it is off-topic here

Comment: @oguzismail Did you **try** running that command yourself? I tried it on 3 systems of mine + a friend's system, same result. I don't think all 4 have messed up permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three commands you might want to run. Note that `--` is recommended in all three cases.

1. `sudo -- "$@"`
2. `doas -- "$@"`
3. `su root -- "$@"`

Since the name of the function implies that you always want `su root` (rather than `su foo` or some other user), there's no point in requiring `root` be included in `SU_CMD`. As such, you can simply write

```
as_root () {
  case $SU_CMD in
    sudo) sudo -- "$@" ;;
    doas) doas -- "$@" ;;
    su) su root -- -c "$*" ;;
    *) printf 'Invalid choice: %s\n' "$SU_CMD" >&2 ;;
  esac
}
```

(This could be refactored, but that hardly seems worth the effort, given the simplicity of the function.)

Comment: This gives me `user bash does not exist` when $@ has the value  `bash <path to executed script> uninstall `, where <path to executed script> is the path to the currently executed script (in this case `./build.sh`, no <>).

Comment: Oh, and if I execute `su root -- bash ./build.sh uninstall` directly it gives me `/usr/bin/bash: /usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file`. Maybe I just should get rid of the redundant `bash` from the calls somehow.

Comment: `su` is used to start a shell, period. It's not really meant to run an arbitrary command as another user. You might use `su root -c "$*"` (the argument to `-c` must be a single string, as `-c` and `"$*"` are both sent as arguments to the user's default shell), though that might cause issues depending on what the arguments to `as_root` actually are.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single dash instead of two or better yet -l to avoid confusion:

```
as_root() {
    if [[ -n $SU_CMD ]]; then
        $SU_CMD "$@";
    else
        su root -l -c "$@";
    fi
}

morbeo@pc:~$ as_root whoami
Password:
root
```

Comment: This seems to work in some contexts and others not. I'll investigate.